How to prove the convergence of ACF in AR(2) model
Consider an AR(2) model:$$
y_t=\phi_0+\phi_1 y_{t-1}+\phi_2 y_{t-2}+e_t \text {, where } e_t \sim \text { i.i.d. }\left(0, \sigma^2\right)
$$
To ensure stationarity, we have:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
\phi_2+\phi_1<1 \\
\phi_2-\phi_1<1 \\
-1<\phi_2<1
\end{array}\right.
$$
I'm trying to prove the model is short memory, that is to prove the ACF $\rho_j$ converges to zero when $j$ goes to infinity. In this case, $$
\begin{aligned}
\rho_1 & =\frac{\gamma_1}{\gamma_0}=\frac{\phi_1}{1-\phi_2} \\
\rho_2 & =\phi_1 \rho_1+\phi_2=\frac{\phi_1^2}{1-\phi_2}+\phi_2 \\
\rho_j & =\phi_1 \rho_{j-1}+\phi_2 \rho_{j-2}, \quad \text { for } \quad j \geq 3
\end{aligned}
$$
I try to use Cauchy inequity:$$\rho_j^2 = (\phi_1 \rho_{j-1}+\phi_2 \rho_{j-2})^2 \leq (\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2)(\rho_{j-1}^2+\rho_{j-2}^2)$$
and then iteratively $\leq (\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2)^2(\rho_{j-2}^2+2\rho_{j-3}^2+\rho_{j-4}^2)$ and so one. In this way, I can construct $(\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2)^k$ which converges to zero quickly as $(\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2) <1$ based on stationarity conditions. But I failed to prove the right part $\rho_{j-k}^2+C_k^1\rho_{j-k-1}^2+…+C_k^p\rho^2_{j-k-p}+…+\rho_{j-2k}^2$ is bounded.
Can anyone help me to prove the boundness or tell me another way to verify the short memory? And by the way, is there any general method for higher order of AR(p) models?

Hi: The stationarity conditions ( which you wrote down ) imply that $|\phi_1|$ and $|\phi_2|$ are both less than 1.0. Box Jenkins or any decent discussion of the stationarity of the AR(2) has a figure illustrating the stationarity boundaries which I always find enlightening. If you are unable to find an illustration, let me know and I'll find it
